# Custom view being drawn sometimes

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-custom-view

I have a custom view, that is sometimes being drawn and sometimes not .. this is reproduce-able across multiple phone.

Don't know why this is happening .. setDimensions() is being called during the onMeasure call of a GalleryGridElement (relative layout) which I use as gallery elements in my recyclerview.

One example would be .. going into the recycler view gallery activity, the circular progress view is there .. when you leave the activity and come back .. onResume creates a new adapter and gives it to the recycler view .. however the circular progress views don't show this time:

```
public class CircularProgressView extends View {

private Paint mIndicatorColour;
private RectF mIndicatorRect;
private Paint mBackCircleColour;

private static final float START_ANGLE = -90;
private volatile float mStopAngle = 0;

private float mOutterCircleStrokeWidth = 20;
private float mInnerCircleStrokeWidth = 16;

private float mViewWidth = 0, mViewHeight = 0;
private volatile int mCurrentProgress = 0;

private ExecutorService mExecutorService;

public CircularProgressView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setUp();
}

public CircularProgressView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setUp();
}

public CircularProgressView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    setUp();
}

private void setUp(){

    mIndicatorRect = new RectF(0,0,300,300);

    mIndicatorColour = new Paint();
    mIndicatorColour.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D62F85"));
    mIndicatorColour.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mIndicatorColour.setStrokeWidth(mInnerCircleStrokeWidth);
    mIndicatorColour.setAntiAlias(true);
    mIndicatorColour.setDither(true);
    mIndicatorColour.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mIndicatorColour.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    mBackCircleColour = new Paint();
    mBackCircleColour.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mBackCircleColour.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mBackCircleColour.setStrokeWidth(mOutterCircleStrokeWidth);
    mBackCircleColour.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBackCircleColour.setDither(true);
    mBackCircleColour.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mBackCircleColour.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    mExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

}

public void setDimensions(float width, int scaleCircleThicknessValue){
    mViewHeight = width;
    mViewWidth = width;
    mIndicatorRect.left = mIndicatorRect.top = mOutterCircleStrokeWidth;
    mIndicatorRect.right = mIndicatorRect.bottom = width - mOutterCircleStrokeWidth;
    mIndicatorColour.setStrokeWidth(mInnerCircleStrokeWidth);
    mBackCircleColour.setStrokeWidth(mOutterCircleStrokeWidth);

    mInnerCircleStrokeWidth = (0.1f * scaleCircleThicknessValue) * width;
    mOutterCircleStrokeWidth = mInnerCircleStrokeWidth + 5;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int desiredWidth = Math.round(mViewWidth);
    int desiredHeight = Math.round(mViewHeight);

    int width;
    int height;

    //Measure Width
    if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        //Must be this size
        width = widthSize;
    } else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        //Can't be bigger than...
        width = Math.min(desiredWidth, widthSize);
    } else {
        //Be whatever you want
        width = desiredWidth;
    }

    //Measure Height
    if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        //Must be this size
        height = heightSize;
    } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        //Can't be bigger than...
        height = Math.min(desiredHeight, heightSize);
    } else {
        //Be whatever you want
        height = desiredHeight;
    }

    //Set values
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawArc(mIndicatorRect, 0, 360, false, mBackCircleColour);
    canvas.drawArc(mIndicatorRect, START_ANGLE, mStopAngle, false, mIndicatorColour);
}

public synchronized void setProgress(final int progress) {

    if ((mCurrentProgress != progress) && (progress > 0)) {

        mCurrentProgress = progress;

        mExecutorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                final float currentAngle = mStopAngle;

                float newAngle = (360f * ((float) progress / 100f));

                float step = (Math.round(newAngle) - Math.round(currentAngle)) <= 1 ? 1 : (newAngle - currentAngle)/5f;

                if (step < 0.01) {
                    newAngle = 359;
                }

                for (float i = currentAngle; i < newAngle; i += step) {
                    try {
                        mStopAngle = i;
                        postInvalidate();
                        Thread.sleep(1000 / 60);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        });


    }
}

public float getProgress(){
    return (360f-mStopAngle) < 1f ? 1 : mStopAngle / 360f;
}


}
```

Comment: Can you log and see whether `onDraw()` is called?

Comment: onMeasure is called ... so im guessing onDraw must be called ?

Comment: Yes, it should. But is it?

Comment: Haha of course .. its not drawing ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just following up on this incase someone runs into this issue:

Since I am using a custom view inside a custom view with the recycler view.
When I bind the view-holder to model, I make sure to completely re-render the view ... ie :

```
    mCircularProgressView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    mCircularProgressView.setDimensions(getWidth() * 0.82f, 1);
    mCircularProgressView.requestLayout();
    mCircularProgressView.postInvalidate();
```

This makes sure the view is drawn no matter what.